# Navigation.pop() and Navigation.push() acting strangely

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I'm creating a Sign-Up section in my application using Flutter and I'm trying to do the following:

> 1. The user clicks Sign-Up
> 2. The user presses the back button at any stage during sign-up
> 3. Then an alert dialog pops up asking if the user really wants to leave sign-up process
> 4. The user presses **Yes**
> 5. The user is then taken back to the first (main) page of the app.

This works for the first page after I click sign-up, but when I get to the second page, **step 4** keeps me on the same page, then when I try it again, it works. But this shouldn't be the case.

After some debugging, I found the issue, but I don't know why it's happening.

I wrote the issue as a comment in my second code snippet, at the end of the `onBackPressed()` function so it's clear as to where it's breaking :).

Here is my code for navigating to the sign-up process page from my **main.dart**:

```dart
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp())
)
```

Then for each page during the sign-up process, whenever I go onto the next page I do a `Navigation.pop(context)` to **pop** the current sign-up page off the stack the do a `Navigation.push()` right after to push the next page on.

Here is the code for the back button functionality in each sign-up page:

```dart
bool backIsPressed = false;
Tools _tools = new Tools();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  BackButtonInterceptor.add(onBackPressed);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  BackButtonInterceptor.remove(onBackPressed);
  super.dispose();
}

bool onBackPressed(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent) {
  this.backIsPressed = !backIsPressed;

  if(backIsPressed) {
    _tools.yesNoAlert(
      context,
      "Going Back?",
      "Are you sure you want back? Changes made will not be saved.",
          () {
        this.backIsPressed = false;
        Navigator.pop(context, true);
      },
          () {
        this.backIsPressed = false;
        Navigator.pop(context, false);
      },
    ).then((res) {
      // ---------------- BREAKS HERE -----------------
      // "res" returns null the first time YES is pressed
      // But Navigation.pop(context, true) should return true according to Flutter's docs
      if(res) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    });

  }
  else {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  return true;
}
```

And lastly, the `yesOrNoAlert()` function in the `Tools` class.

```dart
Future<bool> yesNoAlert(BuildContext context, String title,
    String description, Function yesFunction, Function noFunction) {
  this._isDialogOpen = true;
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text(title),
          content: new Text(description),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text('Yes'),
              onPressed: () {
                _isDialogOpen = false;
                yesFunction();
              },
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text('No'),
              onPressed: () {
                _isDialogOpen = false;
                noFunction();
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      });
}
```

Hope I explained this well.

Comment: From where are you calling onBackPressed()?

Comment: @PabloBarrera - It is set as the `BackButtonIterceptor` in the `initState` method.

Answer (score 1):

if you want go back to the first page, instead of pop(), you can use popUntil() when the user selects yes... no need to pass “res”

Learn more about it here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html